# how to traverse through multiple csv files in php

Tags: php, csv

I have a form,i want to take value from form and check this value to the value in csv file. But it can be in any of the multiple csv files.

So how can i traverse through multiple csv files

For example, I have 50 csv files i want to traverse through these 50 csv files until i get the appropriate result.

I know how to traverse through 1 csv file code i used for this is written below

```
<?PHP
function readCSV($csvFile){
$file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
}
fclose($file_handle);
return $line_of_text;
}
// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'test.csv';
$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Like this how can i traverse through multiple csv files.

Comment: why don't you loop the `readCSV()` function with a list of CSV file names?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor thanks for replay...can you please eplain it in detail?csv files are of diferent name and it contain in folder which may not contain not only csv files..plz help me..

Comment: added full answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
$files = glob('/path/to/dir/*.csv');
foreach($files as $f) {
  $csv = readCSV($f);
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($csv);
  echo '</pre>';
}
```

Reference: [glob()](http://www.php.net/glob) - function to list files in specific directory with specific pattern

Comment: thanks for answer,but when i try to execute it,it takes large amount of time and my firefox crashed.i think it is due to amount of data in csv files...is there any method to solve this issue and make the traversal faster –

Comment: what are you trying to do? print all CSV data on screen? that will cost a lot of time if you have huge amount of data, of course.